# dataframe column str replace with list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
>>> df1
  % score  (C)  D; start name
0     one    0   0        foo
1     one    1   2        bar
2     two    2   4        foo
3   three    3   6        bar
4     two    4   8        foo
5     two    5  10        bar
6     one    6  12        foo
7   three    7  14        foo
>>> char1 = ["\s+" , "(" , ")" , "%" , ";"]
>>> char2 = ["_" , "" , "", "percent" , ""]
```

I have dataframe as given above . I want to rename columns name by replacing special character given in char1 with char2 . that is char1[0] shall be replaced with char[2] . I prefer using df.columns.str.replace. how this can be done in pythonic way ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why not create a dictionary of replacements and use that in the `.replace()` function?

Comment: I think @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's solution is better and more generic - it'll dynamically escape all special RegEx characters, so I'd recommend you to accept his answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [23]: char1 = [r"\s+" , r"\(" , r"\)", r"%" , r";"]

In [24]: df.columns = df.columns.to_series().replace(char1, char2, regex=True).tolist()

In [25]: df
Out[25]:
  percent_score  C   D start_name
0           one  0   0        foo
1           one  1   2        bar
2           two  2   4        foo
3         three  3   6        bar
4           two  4   8        foo
5           two  5  10        bar
6           one  6  12        foo
7         three  7  14        foo
```

Comment: Whoops, didn't see the requirement for the columns.

Comment: I realise now it won't work because of the way the list is defined. Your answer is correct, I will delete mine.

Answer (score 1):

Start by escaping the strings in `char1`. Then build a mapping of `char1` → `char2`, and pass that to `pd.Series.replace` on the columns.

```
import re

char1 = [r"\s+" , r"(" , r")" , r"%" , r";"]
char2 = ["_" , "" , "", "percent" , ""]
```

```
mapping = dict(zip((re.escape(c) if '\\' not in c else c for c in char1), char2))
# this next step is similar to MaxU's solution
df.columns = df.columns.to_series().replace(mapping, regex=True)

df

  percent_score  C   D start_name
0           one  0   0        foo
1           one  1   2        bar
2           two  2   4        foo
3         three  3   6        bar
4           two  4   8        foo
5           two  5  10        bar
6           one  6  12        foo
7         three  7  14        foo
```

Comment: I get this: `TypeError: dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 2`

Comment: @AshishAcharya, Trying using `zip` on the arguments.

Comment: @AshishAcharya Sorry, there were some bugs that I had to squash.

Comment: now it works and looks better compared to mine solution! :)